# Most recent record within 3 months if one exists

Tags: sql, date, report

I am working with a report writer (DataInsights). In this particular report some clients have a "Special Rate" and some don't. For those that do, there is an expiration date. Currently, the report is yielding several lines per client that has a Special Rate because each spell of a special rate is generating it's own line. We would like a simple SQL statement that will maintain all the records that do not have  a "Special Rate" and only returns a line for the most  recent "Special Rate" "Expiration Date" if it falls within the last 3 months . (if there is no way to limit it to the last 3 months, then that's okay, we just need the most recent line)

Example:

(current)

```
Name        Client #        Rate        Exp. Date  
John Doe        12345       Special     01/12/2014  
John Doe        12345       Special     01/12/2015  
John Doe        12345       Special     01/12/2016  
Jane White      78965  
Dixie Brown     45879       Exceptional 07/30/2011  
Dixie Brown     45879       Exceptional 07/30/2012  
Dixie Brown     45879       Exceptional 07/30/2013
```

(should be)

```
John Doe        12345       Special     01/12/2016  
Jane White      78965   
Dixie Brown     45879
```

Comment: what type of sql, PL SQL?

Comment: It would help to see table structures, sample data, expected output, what you've tried and why it didn't work (wrong data, error message, etc.). Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select Name, Client, Rate, Date as Special_Date
 from yourtable
  INNER JOIN
        (
          select max(Date ) Date , Name, Client
          from yourtable
          group by  Name, Client
        ) thedatetable
```

Answer (score 0):

If your name, client, and rate are always the same per group as in your sample data, then you can just group by them returning the max(expdt).  To get all records where there is no special rate and limiting ones that do to 3 months, add them as filters (using OR).  Used SQL Server syntax below and edited some data a bit to fall within 3 month limit:

```
WITH testdata(Name, Client, Rate, expdt)
AS(       select 'John Doe',    12345, 'Special',    '01/12/2016'  
union all select 'John Doe',    12345, 'Special', '   03/13/2016'  
union all select 'John Doe',    12345, 'Special',    '03/12/2016'  
union all select 'Jane White',  78965,  NULL,         NULL 
union all select 'Dixie Brown', 45879, 'Exceptional', '07/30/2016'  
union all select 'Dixie Brown', 45879, 'Exceptional', '07/30/2016'  
union all select 'Dixie Brown', 45879, 'Exceptional', '07/30/2016' 
)

select Name, client, Rate, max(expdt) expdt from testdata
where Rate is NULL 
  or  expdt>=DATEADD(month, -3, GETDATE())
group by Name, client, Rate
```

OUTPUT:

```
Name        client Rate        expdt           
----------- ------ ----------- ---------- 
Dixie Brown 45879  Exceptional 07/30/2016 
Jane White  78965  null        null       
John Doe    12345  Special     03/12/2016
```